# Loading a model into Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `fit` from a xgboost. I would like to make a shiny app that simply takes input values and outputs predictions. On my desktop I have `predict(fit,data)`. Is it possible to load the `fit` object into shiny? I would prefer not to have to upload our data, retrain the model, then output a prediction all on the server. I essentially want a shiny app that simply outputs results from `predict(fit,data)`, where the fit is uploaded and the data is input by the user. Any resources/links to how to do this would be helpful.

Comment: Save the model `fit` into .Rda file and then `load` it. e.g. 
`load('fit.RData',.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: This worked! Thanks

Comment: To mark this question complete, please provide a small answer yourself and mark it complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_local_file.rmd`

```
fit<-xgboost(..args..)
save(fit, file = "../my_shiny_app/my-fitted-boost.rda")
```

`my_shiny_app.R`

```
library(xgboost)
fit_boost <- load(file = "my-fitted-boost.rda",.GlobalEnv)
predict(fit_boost, data)
```